# Read and process large one line JSON file

Tags: java, json

I have a large json file(200 MB), but all are in one single line.

I need to do some processing with the data in the file and write the data in to a relational database.

What is the best way we can do this using java.

Note: Most of the available methods are using line by line reading. Also We can use thing like MappedByteBuffer to read by characters but it is not an efficient solution 
Non java solutions are also welcome

Comment: Use any of the several JSON parsing libraries available, such as GSON. [GSON's `JsonReader`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#JsonReader(java.io.Reader)) reads from a `Reader`, there are several non-line-based `Reader`s ([`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), for instance). It probably doesn't read all of the text into memory before processing it, though of course, you can always [check the source](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the library from Douglas Crackford https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java, use the following command to load a json array.

```
org.json.JSONArray mediaArray = new org.json.JSONArray(filecontent);
```

Check the following article for read a file content.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42